# Join 2 select statements

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

How can I join these two select statements:
I tried adding @formateurs to the second query but it does not work.

First query:

```
DECLARE @formateurs varchar(max)
SET @formateurs = ''

SELECT @formateurs = @formateurs + distinct(formateur) 
FROM onglet_forma_salles 
WHERE code = '0000001' 
ORDER BY Sort

SELECT @formateurs
```

Second query:

```
SELECT code, u_date, cardname, @formateurs
FROM session s
JOIN onglet_forma_salles ofs ON s.code = ofs.code
WHERE s.code = '0000001'
GROUP BY u_date
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Add sample table data, and the expected result. (We can't figure out what you want otherwise.)

Comment: **distinct is NOT a function** Are you wanting a comma separated list of the column onglet_forma_salles.formateur? for that you can use STUFF( with FOR XML PATH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should provide a distinct list of [formateurs] (separated by comma)

```
SELECT
      g.code, g.u_date, g.cardname, fxp.formateurs
FROM (
      SELECT
            code
          , u_date
          , cardname
      FROM session s
            JOIN onglet_forma_salles ofs ON s.code = ofs.code
      WHERE s.code = '0000001'
      GROUP BY
            u_date
) AS g
      OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT
                  STUFF((
                        SELECT DISTINCT
                              ',' + formateur
                        FROM onglet_forma_salles
                        WHERE g.code = onglet_forma_salles.code
                        FOR xml PATH (''), TYPE
                  )
                  .value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                  , 1, 1, '')
      ) AS fxp (formateurs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax of your 2nd query would be like :-

```
    DECLARE @formateurs varchar(max)
    SET @formateurs = ''

    SELECT s.code, u_date, cardname, @formateurs
    FROM session s JOIN onglet_forma_salles ofs 
    ON s.code = ofs.code
    WHERE s.code = '0000001'
    GROUP BY s.code, u_date, cardname
```